# ajax update not working inside ui:composition

Tags: primefaces

When I fully insert the form in the main page it works, but when I use ui:include it doesn't.

```
<!-- Main JSF -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <ui:include src="main.xhtml" />
  </h:body>
</html>

<!-- to be included -->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="ID" for="userId" />
    <p:inputText value="#{managedEmployee.userId}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Show" update="result" />
    <p:panel id="result">
      <h:outputText value="#{managedEmployee.userId}" />
    </p:panel>
  </h:form> 
</ui:composition>
```

Hope this explains my intentions.
I've been searching for an answer the whole day but without success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this ticket, I found the issue for my problem here, used wrong bean reference, kinda stupid I know..

Answer (score 0):

Try change to (with slash):

```
<ui:include src="/main.xhtml" />
```

Comment: Just tried but doesn't work. The included page get's loaded but the update is not functioning.

Comment: Do you have some exception in logs?
Is value of userId visible after page loading?

Comment: When I run the application this is shown: WARNING: Unable to find component with ID userId in view.

Comment: Becausue you have outputLabel for="userId" and the p:inputText hasn't got id parameter.

Comment: I actually failed to notice I used the wrong bean reference so it works now. But I made this 'test' project to see if the code was correct. And I just figured out why my main project was failing. If I set the default page to this it works. But if I use an intro page as default and then navigate to this page, it stops working. So I might have to make a new ticket :s. Thanks for your help anyway. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because in the file you are trying to include, you need to use  tags.

Read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/) tutorial very carefully. It explains a lot.