# ui:include with method breaks the jsf's ajax function

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I'm facing a pretty similar issue on which I already made a ticket but now the problem arises in my main project. The previous ticket involved a test project.
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650565/ajax-update-not-working-inside-uicomposition) the link to the ticket. I'll first explain my project briefly and then provide the code.

It's a basic ui since I left out irrelevant parts, but when you start the webapp you should be directed to the main page which has an intro loaded through the use of ajax. I'm using a managedbean called Navigation which is a simple pojo with 2 annotations and one string property called 'page'. I've set the property to 'intro', so it's loaded by default.

```java
// Navigation.java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Navigation {

  private String page = "intro";

  public String getPage() {
      return page;
  }

  public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
  }
}
```

index.xhtml looks like this:

```html
<!-- index.xhtml -->
<h:body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" action="#{navigation.setPage('intro')}" update=":contentPanel" />
            <p:submenu label="Actions" icon="ui-icon-transferthick-e-w">
                <p:submenu label="Employee">
                    <p:menuitem value="Search" action="#{navigation.setPage('employee/find')}" update=":contentPanel" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
    <!-- ContentPanel -->
    <p:panel id="contentPanel" styleClass="content">
       <ui:include src="/#{navigation.page}.xhtml" />
    </p:panel>
</h:body>
```

Now, when you navigate to 'Actions/Employee/Create new' the file find.xhtml does get loaded into the main page but, the form itself doesn't work. Here's the file:

```html
<!-- find.xhtml -->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:facet name="header">
      Create new employee
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel value="User ID: " for="userId" />
    <p:inputText value="#{managedEmployee.userId}" id="userId" />
    <p:commandButton value="Show" update="result" />
    <h:outputText id="result" value="#{managedEmployee.userId}" />
</ui:composition>
```

So a user would be able to input a userId in the form and it would be displayed near the form when commandbutton is pressed. Obviously I must be doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't like saying it, but I'm desperate for an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem. Not sure what the reason is but if I surround the code in ui:composition with h:form and add that form id to update on the link it works.
Hope this helps others when they encounter it. Cheers

```html
<p:menuitem value="Create" action="#{navigationBean.setPage('employee/create')}" update=":contentPanel :form" />
```

```html
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:form id="form">
    ...
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question, but you don't have an action set on your commandButton so of course it's not going to do anything.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Show" update="result" />
```

should have something like

```
 <p:commandButton value="Show" update="result" action="#{backer.method}"/>
```

Comment: I don't think that's it, because when I manually include the file like this: <ui:include src="/employee/find.xhtml" />, the form works. But when I use #{navigation.page} and navigate to the form, the form does get loaded onto the main page but stops working.

Comment: Oh i think i understand what you're asking now. Can you verify that the generated html markup is the same when doing it both ways? Also do you get an error in your console at all?

Comment: I don't see any errors and the sources appears to match. I've been looking into the matter and it could be this has something to do with client and server side.